# How to remove blank lines from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
          Type         Channel       Agt
0                                       
1     ServiceList          DCS          
2                                       
3                                       
4     ServiceList          WEB          
5                                       
6                                       
7     ServiceSearch         TA     95AKSJAPI
```

Expected output:

```
          Type          Channel       Agt                      
0     ServiceList          DCS                         
1     ServiceList          WEB          
2     ServiceSearch        TA      95AKSJAPI
```

I tried using

**df.dropna(inplace=True)**

I am getting output as

```
           Type        Channel       Agt                     
0     ServiceSearch      TA     95AKSJAPI
```

Comment: Try [`df.dropna(how='all')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df[~df.eq('').all(1)]
```

if you have NaN instead of empty strings, then yes you can do as Remmelzwaal mentioned in the comment or `df[~df.isna().all(1)]`

Output:

```
            Type Channel        Agt
1    ServiceList     DCS           
4    ServiceList     WEB           
7  ServiceSearch      TA  95AKSJAPI
```

Comment: Wouldn't my suggestion work either way, since `dropna(inplace=True)` seemed to drop all rows with at least one empty value?

Comment: empty space is not NaN if I m not wrong.